# Are there any RSS-to-email gateways that provide for periodic emails less frequently than every day?

Tags: email, rss, gateway, web-application, services

Once a week is ideally what I'm looking for (as opposed to something like [this](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/))

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at "Website Watcher" http://www.aignes.com/ which can do that and more ! ;)

hope this helps ;)